# How to filter Plotly histogram based on an additional column

Tags: python, plotly, data-science

So I have a dataset that looks similar to the following:

| Procedure | Country | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Colectomy | China | 2019 |
| Colectomy | India | 2020 |
| Appendectomy | China | 2020 |
| Appendectomy | USA | 2010 |

I currently am plotting a histogram of procedure frequencies with the following code:

`plotly.express.histogram(df, x = 'Procedure', color = 'Country')`

It looks exactly how I want it to. However, I am looking to make some sort of slider or dropdown that allows me to filter the data presented based on the 'Year' column. Ideally, I could either only visualize procedures from a certain year, or visualize all procedures that occur after a particularly year. I am looking to do this in real time with Plotly. I've looked at the documentation and they seem to only have examples that let you filter based on the x or y argument. Does anybody know how to do this?
Note: I am using regular Plotly, not Dash.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dataframe by the values in a named column like so

```py
date_filter = df[(df['year'] >= '2020') & (df['year'] < '2022')]
```

would filter based on your year column and return the rows between 2020 and 2022

you could then plot with

```py
plotly.express.histogram(date_filter, x = 'Procedure', color = 'Country')
```

[some more filtering examples](https://datagy.io/filter-pandas/)

Comment: I want to be able to do it in real time via Plotly (not beforehand with Pandas). I will add that clarification to the post.

Comment: you want to do it in real time with UI elements like sliders, but you don't want to use dash? because dash would make that pretty straightforward. You'd create a slider and update the filtered dataframe from the callback